# Using iterator on only parts of model in ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iteration

I have created a model in ModelBuilder using ArcMap 10.7.1 which is using an iterator.

Is it possible to exclude parts of my model from being "iterated"?

Answer (score 3):

Everything in a model will loop as many times as an iterator, even tools not connected or upstream of the iterator. This simple example shows this:

[image: Example]

*The Add Field keeps running and failing.*

A way of stopping tools executing is to provide a precondition and connect it to the tool, If it evaluates as *False* then the tool will not run, if *True* then it runs. You could do this by adding a boolean variable and making it the precondition. Be aware that this may have unforeseen implications in downstream processing.

[image: Boolean switch]

Answer (score 2):

To exclude parts of your model being run, you'll want to pull those out of the model with the iterator, and into their OWN model. From that model you can call the model that makes use of an iterator.

This would be the model-in-a-model scenario.

The [help outlines this here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-iterators-for-iteration-looping-.htm):

> If an iterator is added to a model, all tools
>   in the model iterate for each value in the iterator. If you do not
>   want to run each tool in the model for each iterated value, create a
>   submodel/model within a model/nested model that contains only the
>   iterator and add it as a model tool into the main model

With a nice, [well laid out example here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-model-within-a-model.htm) in the **Advanced use of model iterators** section.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this seems possible to be done only in ArcGIS Pro were a new parameter has been installed within the "iterate" function with the name "Layer Type".
Layer Type allows you to select only the variable(s) that you want the looping to occur and not the rest.
My nightmare today...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).